# How to use Google sign with a redirect instead of a new window?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-signin, google-identity

I am using a Google App Engine (Java) with Google Cloud Endpoints. I would like to use Endpoint's built in authentication, and am doing so successfully with [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

Can you change the sign-in button behavior so that upon clicking the button the user is redirected to the Google sign in page and back rather than a new window opening? This would really improve the UX, especially for mobile.

In addition, is it possible to redirect non logged-in users automatically to the sign in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no possible way to get the login into the same window. You can definitely post a Feature Request for such a thing on our issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

As to answer your second question, yes it is possible to send non logged-in users directly to the sign in. You just need to check, at the top of your handler, if the user is signed in, and kick off the authentication flow if he isn't.

Comment: You said "yes it is possible to send logged-in users directly", I asked about non logged in users. The issue here seems to be with pop up blockers. If the log in is a separate window, this would have to be invoked via user action.

Comment: @marcM that was a typo, I was meaning non logged in. Anyway even if I understand that popup blockers can be a  problem, your best bet is still a feature request ^^